# object mode, can not cancel select

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm in object mode in blender 2.81, and I select 1 object, and then I click on empty area, it does not cancel the selection, I can not drag mouse to select multiple objects.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Perhaps you've accidentally changed some configuration that causes this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You may have disabled *Meshes* in the *View Object Types* menu.

[image: enter link description here]

Or less likely might be in tweaks mode, click and hold the mouse to change back to box select.

[image: enter link description here]